# Java LostFocus and InputVerifier, moving in reverse-tab-order

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a GUI application that uses an InputVerifier to check the content of text fields before yielding the focus. This is all very normal. Yesterday, however, discovered a problem - it seems to be a bug, but I cannot find any mention of it anywhere. Before I report this as a bug, I thought I would ask: am I missing something obvious here?

Situation:

- A set of text fields with InputVerifiers.
- Listeners for FocusLost and FocusGained on all controls, so I can see what is happening.
- A separate thread uses a DefaultKeyboardFocusManager to report (every 2 seconds) which control has the focus.
- I place invalid data in a JTextField in the middle of the form, and try to leave the control.

If I try to move away from this control using the mouse, or using the tab-key, I cannot. The FocusLost event does not fire and the control properly retains the focus.

However, if I try to move away from the control *in reverse tab order, using Shift-Tab*, **sometimes** the FocusLost event fires. If this happens, the separate thread reports that **no control has the focus**, i.e., getFocusOwner() returns null.

---

Edit: below is a small sample program that shows the problem. The problem has nothing to do with the extra thread - the thread is just there to make the problem more obvious. If there is a race-condition, it is somewhere in Swing.

To see the problem, go to the second text box and empty it. The control should retain the focus, and does so *unless* you leave it by pressing shift-tab. Unlike the full application, the error seems to occur here 100% of the time. This is true both under OpenJDK 6 and under Oracle Java 7.

This is almost too obvious to be a bug, plus it happens in multiple Java environments. Hence, my suspicion that I am missing something obvious. Anyone?

```
public class FocusBugDemo extends JFrame {
    static JTextField txtOne = new JTextField("Ignore this control");
    static JTextField txtTwo = new JTextField("Delete this text, then press shift-tab");
    static JLabel lblFocus = new JLabel("");
    static KeyboardFocusManager kfm = new DefaultKeyboardFocusManager();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FocusBugDemo();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    Component c = kfm.getFocusOwner();
                    String focusInfo = "elsewhere";
                    if (c == null) {                        focusInfo = "null";
                    } else if (c == txtOne) {       focusInfo = "txtOne";
                    } else if (c == txtTwo) {       focusInfo = "txtTwo";
                    }
                    lblFocus.setText(System.currentTimeMillis() + " - Focus owner " + focusInfo);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    private FocusBugDemo() {
        super("Focus bug demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        NotEmpty validator = new NotEmpty();
        txtOne.setInputVerifier(validator);
        txtTwo.setInputVerifier(validator);
        add(txtOne);
        add(txtTwo);
        add(lblFocus);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class NotEmpty extends InputVerifier {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            JTextField txtField = (JTextField) input;
            return (txtField.getText().length() > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: _separate thread_? _sometimes_? Sounds like a data race. How do you synchronize access to data shared data?

Comment: Shouldn't you create the GUI on the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now reported to Oracle as bug [7167871](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7167871).

Comment: Link is there (click on the bug number) - it apparently just takes a couple of days before the link actually works at Oracle...

Answer (score 1):

Using your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe on Mac OS X, Java 6, which supports @CatalinaIsland's observation. In particular, focus never leaves an empty text field using either <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift-tab</kbd>; focus becomes `null` only when the frame is deactivated.

I see two threads accessing multiple fields with no synchronization at all. At a minimum, you should use `EventQueue.invokeLater()` in `t` to update the GUI, as described in [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and show below.

The broader question is this: What focus problem are you trying to solve using `t`?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FocusDemo {

    private static final JTextField txtOne =
        new JTextField("Ignore this control");
    private static final JTextField txtTwo =
        new JTextField("Delete this text, then press shift-tab");
    private static final JLabel lblFocus = new JLabel("");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FocusDemo();
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        KeyboardFocusManager kfm =
                            new DefaultKeyboardFocusManager();

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Component c = kfm.getFocusOwner();
                            String focusInfo = "elsewhere";
                            if (c == null) {
                                focusInfo = "null";
                            } else if (c == txtOne) {
                                focusInfo = "txtOne";
                            } else if (c == txtTwo) {
                                focusInfo = "txtTwo";
                            }
                            lblFocus.setText(System.currentTimeMillis()
                                + " - Focus owner " + focusInfo);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    private FocusDemo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Focus bug demo");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
                NotEmpty validator = new NotEmpty();
                txtOne.setInputVerifier(validator);
                txtTwo.setInputVerifier(validator);
                f.add(txtOne);
                f.add(txtTwo);
                f.add(lblFocus);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class NotEmpty extends InputVerifier {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            JTextField txtField = (JTextField) input;
            return (txtField.getText().length() > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted above, the thread "t" is completely irrelevant to the problem - the problem exists anyway. Thread "t" is only present to make the problem more obvious by continuously displaying which control has the focus. Running under Linux, the text-field loses the focus with shift-tab, both under the latest versions of Oracle Java 7 and OpenJDK 6. I hadn't tested under Windows or MacOS.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe using either your or my example on Ubuntu 10, OpenJDK 6.

Comment: Thanks for the info - that is really strange, as I have reproduced the effect on two different systems. Let's see what the Oracle folk have to say - I'll provide further info as required underneath the bug report there...